# Bootstrap .container-fluid with inner columns fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Having in bootstrap, 2 columns into a non fluid container

```
.col-xs-9 / .col-xs-3
```

How can I make backgrounds for this columns to be full width to left and right margin?
I made this example
404: http://codepen.io/iamandrewluca/pen/VmOJVJ
But `width: 75vw;` and `width: 25vw;` does not work as I supposed.
How can I fix this?

wanted result:
* orange - container
* green - left column
* blue - right column
* darkgreen - left background
* darkblue - right background

[image: result]

I can just add

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and give both columns `width: 100vw;` but the background image content will go outside.

Comment: DO you need to make background images fill whole width of viewport?

Comment: Thanks, but nope. Backgrounds should start from the place where columns touch each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with manual using intensive `calc` on widths and margins for `first-of-type` and `last-of-type`.
example: https://codepen.io/iamandrewluca/full/zzWrXe/
Maybe I'll create a mixin to generate this for all columns with offsets, pulls, push, and all other stuff

UPDATE: updated to Bootstrap 4, fixed some problems with scrollable content

Answer (score 0):

Your background images are within a container which has a defined width. You would need to make the container have a width of 100vw, and then the left column to be 75vw, right to be 25vw. Then your background images will cover the whole screen.

Comment: it's called as `container-fluid`, but he doesn't want to use it

Comment: doesnt want to use what?

Comment: container-fluid. OP says: '...into a non fluid container'